# How to view the logging of Google Web App when other users are executing it?

Tags: logging, google-apps-script, web-applications

I deployed my Google App Script Webapp with the optionen `execute the app as: User accessing the web app`.

In the App Script Dashboard I can see the executions of the webapp and the logging. However I only see the logging when I (the owner of the app) executes it. When another user executes the webapp I only see the executions but I can not see the logging int the App Script Dashboard.

How can I also see the logging of the app independent of the user executing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two ways of seeing the executions:

- Allow the other users to edit the script (if it is on developing mode), then you will be able to see all the executions from the Apps Script Dashboard.
- You can link the script to a [GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switch_to_a_different_google_cloud_platform_project), and then you will be able to see the executions from the GCP Logs viewer. You can enter the GCP logs viewer from the script: View -> Stackdriver Logging

Comment: I linked the script to a neww GCP project which did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134374008). Consider adding a star (on the top left) for Google developers to prioritize the  issue.

---

In the mean time, As [mentioned in the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62557720/), Switching GCP should work:

- [Switching Google cloud project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)
- View Logs at View > Stackdriver Logging