Webhook sends and delivers right but google apps script fails
I am currently trying to link a webhook to my google apps script. For some reason, the google apps script is failing to receive the webhook properly and all the execution log shows is "Failed." I am asking for some assistance in if there are any errors in my code. *NOTE: I have replaced the calendar ID and google Meet ID with generic text temporarily. I have set the deployment properly in apps script (to execute as me with anyone having access). I have tested the webhook send from Stripe and Postman and it works properly every time. Apps script is just not receiving the webhook information properly for some reason.
Here is the code:
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    Logger.log("Received POST request.");
    
    if (!e || !e.postData) {
      Logger.log("No postData received.");
      throw new Error("No postData received in the request");
    }
    
    const payload = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    Logger.log("Received payload: " + JSON.stringify(payload));

    if (payload.type === "checkout.session.completed") {
      const session = payload.data.object;
      Logger.log("Session data: " + JSON.stringify(session));

      const customerEmail = session.customer_details.email;
      const customerName = session.customer_details.name;
      Logger.log("Customer Email: " + customerEmail + " | Customer Name: " + customerName);

      if (!customerEmail || !customerName) {
        Logger.log("Missing customer information.");
        throw new Error("Missing customer information in the webhook payload.");
      }

      // Process registration
      checkParticipantLimitAndAssignWebinar(customerName, customerEmail);

      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Webhook processed successfully").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
    }

    Logger.log("Event type not supported: " + payload.type);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Event type not supported").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error: " + error.message);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error: " + error.message).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
}

function checkParticipantLimitAndAssignWebinar(customerName, customerEmail) {
  try {
    Logger.log("Checking participant limit and assigning webinar.");
    
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Transactions");
    if (!sheet) {
      Logger.log("Sheet 'Transactions' not found!");
      throw new Error("Sheet 'Transactions' not found!");
    }

    const calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("google-calendar-link-goes-here");
    const now = new Date();
    const events = calendar.getEvents(now, new Date(now.getFullYear() + 1, now.getMonth(), now.getDate()));
    Logger.log("Fetched events: " + JSON.stringify(events));

    for (const event of events) {
      const eventDate = event.getStartTime();
      const formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(eventDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
      Logger.log("Event Date: " + formattedDate);

      // Count participants for this event date
      const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      Logger.log("Sheet data: " + JSON.stringify(data));
      const participantCount = data.filter(row => row[3] === formattedDate).length;
      Logger.log("Participants for " + formattedDate + ": " + participantCount);

      if (participantCount < 100) {
        // Register participant
        const webinarLink = "hgoogle-meet-link-goes-here"; // Same link for all events
        sendEmailWithWebinarLink(customerName, customerEmail, webinarLink, eventDate);
        sheet.appendRow([new Date(), customerName, customerEmail, formattedDate]);
        return;
      }
    }

    Logger.log("All upcoming webinars are fully booked.");
    throw new Error("All upcoming webinars are fully booked.");
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error in checkParticipantLimitAndAssignWebinar: " + error.message);
    throw error;  // Re-throw the error after logging it
  }
}

function sendEmailWithWebinarLink(name, email, link, eventDate) {
  try {
    Logger.log("Sending email to " + email);
    
    const subject = "Your Webinar Registration Confirmation";
    const body = `
      Hi ${name},

      Thank you for registering for the Effective Leadership webinar! Here are the details:

      Webinar Link: ${link}
      Date & Time: ${Utilities.formatDate(eventDate, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "EEE, MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm a")}

      Please click the link at the scheduled time to join. We look forward to seeing you!

      Best regards,
      DevelUP YOU
    `;

    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
    Logger.log("Email sent to: " + email);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error sending email: " + error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}


Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64002160/
